# User defined function to get a value from a particular row with in the column of the calling function

Tags: excel, vba

I'm wondering if it's possible to write a user define function in VBA to get a value from a fixed row within the column of the calling function.

Ie I have some fixed values on row 2 of a Excel table; I want to refer to those values from a user defined function.

The caveat is I want the value in row 2, of the calling functions column.

**Note** : the actual function is more complex than this, however solving this problem would get me where I need to be.

Pseudocode:

```
Function GetStandardPayment()
    GetStandardPayment = CallingColumn.Row(2).Value
End Function
```

What I have is the following:

```
Function GetStandardPayment()
    GetStandardPayment = ActiveCell.Offset(ActiveCell.Column:2).Value
End Function
```

However it has syntax errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited to remove the possibly unneccessary variable.

You can use the Caller property of the Application object.  When using a UDF in a worksheet cell, this will return a range object -- the cell where the function exists.

```
Function GetStandardPayment()
  Application.Volatile
  GetStandardPayment = Cells(2, Application.Caller.Column)
End Function
```

The Volatile property is used else the function won't update, since there are no cell references in the function argument.